# How can I print from a MacOS app using swiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I can figure out how to add buttons to the menus, but for some reason my many searches can't find a way to open the print dialog from any of them. Ideally, I'd like to send a bunch of formatted text to be printed.

I am basing my App on the Document App template included in Xcode 12.5

```
@main
struct Test: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: TestDocument()) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document)
        }
    }
}

import UniformTypeIdentifiers

extension UTType {
    static var exampleText: UTType {
        UTType(importedAs: "com.example.plain-text")
    }
}

struct TestDocument: FileDocument {
    var text: String

    init(text: String = "Hello, world!") {
        self.text = text
    }

    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.exampleText] }

    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        guard let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents,
              let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
        text = string
    }
    
    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        let data = text.data(using: .utf8)!
        return .init(regularFileWithContents: data)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: TestDocument

    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $document.text)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(document: .constant(TestDocument()))
    }
}
```

I have tried to find anything current in the Apple Documentation, but I have had little to no luck. I can find code for iOS devices, but it doesn't work for the Mac, unfortunately.

It feels like I'm missing something really simple. Any advice, or links would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edited to add:

I figured out something that will work for now, but it doesn't fully fix the issue of the print menu option not showing up. Many of the examples show something like:

```
printOperation.runModal(for: windowControllers[0].window!, delegate: self, didRun: #selector(printOperationDidRun(_:success:contextInfo:)), contextInfo: nil)
```

But, in my case replaced it with:

```
printOperation.run()
```

That at least allows me to bring up the print dialog and go from there. If anyone has an answer for how the swift decides if it should display the print menu item or not I'd still appreciate it. But, for not this at least gives me something that works.

Comment: Don't know if [this](https://thomas.skowron.eu/blog/printing-with-swiftui/) will help

Comment: I'm not aware of any SwiftUI-specific printing tools, but you can certainly use `NSPrintOperation`. Also check out https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_aboutprinting/osxp_aboutprt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000083-SW1

Comment: I have run across the links posted, but I wasn't able to make either of them work. The first issue that is happening is that print isn't showing up as an option in the Edit menu for the app. I suspect that if I could figure that out, it might automatically work for what I wanted. But, I still am struggling to get the code to work to open a print dialog. I have managed to make an iOS app that can print, but unfortunately, the code doesn't work on the Mac.

Comment: @DonEspe were you able to figure out a way to solve this?